# Is addin (excel content add-ins) resize event supported/available in office.js 1.0 or 1.1?

Tags: office-addins, office-js, apps-for-office, javascript-api-for-office

I am looking for add in resize event but not luck so for.

Is add in (excel content add-ins) resize event supported/available in office.js 1.0 or 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using `javascript/jquery window.resize()`

JavaScript:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

jquery:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  ...
});
```